# The constructor RdsHttpErrorResponse(xxxErrorCode.Common) is undefined

Tags: java

I encoutered an error,when I program like this:

```
new RdsHttpErrorResponse(xxxErrorCode.Common.REQ_NULL)
```

First，I hava a constructor，like this：

```
public RdsHttpErrorResponse(ErrorCode code)
{
    this.setErrorCodeAndMgs(code, null);
}
```

And,my enum Common,like this:

```
public class xxxErrorCode{
    public interface ErrorCode
    {
        public int toInt();

        public String toStr(); 
    }

    /**
     * xxxErrorCode Common
     */
     public enum Common implements ErrorCode
     {
        REQ_NULL(6, "CloudFS.0006"), // req_body is null
        ...
        private int code;

        private String strCode; 

        private Common(int code, String strCode)
        {
            this.code = code;
            this.strCode = strCode;
        }

        public int toInt()
        {
            return code;
        }

        public String toStr()
        {
            return strCode;
        }
     }
 }
```

My enum Common have implemented ErrorCode interface.
Why this error?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have known the answer of this question.
The reason is that I copy a class named xxxErrorCode to define a new xxxErrorCode，but the "import" was still the old xxxErrorCode。

So，the inner interface ErrorCode is difference completely!(even though they are identical)

Comment: The "import" was still the old xxxErrorCode， and the old xxxErrorCode.ErrorCode.Yes，it need two “import”。